# How to add link internal or external to an image in a view for a slideshow?

Tags: 7, views, media, javascript

I need a slideshow and sometime the images need to have a link. This link might be external or internal and it is posted by users. I use rewrite results in my view. However, sometimes the picture does not have a link. So this does not work for me.

I am using Drupal 7, Views, link and slideshow, picture module. My content type has the following fields:

- field_slideshow_image
- field_link_in_picture
- text_slideshow

I try used another modules but I need to use the picture module to make my pictures responsiveness.  Other modules require that use the Formatter in views and picture module uses its own format.

Answer (score 1):

I solved using theming in the view. I use the template in the image field. I ended up with a template like views-view-field--field-slideshow-image.tpl.php.

```
  <?php 
//dpm($row); only work if devel module enabled

$url='';

if (!empty($row->field_field_link_in_picture_)){

    $url=($row->field_field_link_in_picture_[0]['raw']['url']); 

}

if (!empty($url)) { 
     echo "<a href='$url'>" .$output ."</a>"; //print image with link    
}
else {
    print $output; //print image
}

?>
```

If someone knows a better way to do this please feel post it here. If I am not doing something in the Drupal way please let me know or you have another way to accomplish this. I would love to hear it :)

If you know little  about theming views you can check this video to understand better
[Theming Views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Cfc11_sb5M)

Answer (score -1):

I would also use

```
//dpm($row); only work if devel module enabled
$url='';
if (!empty($row->field_field_link_in_picture_)){
  $url=($row->field_field_link_in_picture_[0]['raw']['url']); 
}
if (!empty($url)) { 
  echo "<a href='$url'>" .$output ."</a>"; //print image with link    
}
else {
  print $output; //print image
}
```